# Multiplication in VBA For Loop

Tags: excel, vba, forms, for-loop, multiplication

have a problem, I need to create a multiplication table range from 11 to 20 but it needs to be output in B2 not in its generic value, so when I write in my code using a for loop I can not get it to output the results anywhere else in the sheet and I need it to output the result table to B2.

The output goes from K11 to T20 , but I need these results to output from B1 to K10.
Any help will be much appreciated!

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
For i = 11 To 20
For x = 11 To 20
cells(i, x) = i * x
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `cells(i-10, x-9) = i * x`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
For x = 2 To 11
Cells(i , x) = (i + 10) * (x + 9)
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A good option it to set some variables beforehand and then use offset:

```
Sub Main()
        
    Dim ST_RG As Range  'Start range, this is where your values will begin being output
    Dim Y As Long       'Y axis count
    Dim X As Long       'X axis count
    Dim lFrom As Long   'Count From
    Dim lTo As Long     'Count To
    
    ' Set all your parameters here:
    Set ST_RG = Sheet4.Range("A1")
    lFrom = 11
    lTo = 20
    
    For Y = lFrom To lTo
        For X = lFrom To lTo
            ST_RG.Offset(Y - lFrom, X - lFrom).Value = Y * X
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Create Multiplication Table

- The best place for the `WriteMultiplicationTable` procedure is in a standard module e.g. `Module1`, so you could easily call it from any other module.
- Be careful to adjust the correct cell since you're first mentioning cell `B2` and later the range `B1:K10`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range("B1")
    WriteMultiplicationTable fCell, 11, 20
    
    ' Alternatively, if the command button is in the worksheet where
    ' you want to create the table, instead of the previous, you could use
    ' the following one-liner:
    'WriteMultiplicationTable Me.Range("B1"), 11, 20

End Sub

Sub WriteMultiplicationTable( _
        ByVal FirstCell As Range, _
        ByVal StartNumber As Long, _
        ByVal EndNumber As Long)
    
    Dim Data() As Long
    ReDim Data(StartNumber To EndNumber, StartNumber To EndNumber)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = StartNumber To EndNumber
        For c = StartNumber To EndNumber
            Data(r, c) = r * c
        Next c
    Next r
    
    Dim nCount As Long: nCount = EndNumber - StartNumber + 1
    
    FirstCell.Cells(1).Resize(nCount, nCount).Value = Data
    
End Sub
```